# valuechange event similar functionality in c or c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm implementing a global debug module ,a single module contains a struct to hold all global variables in C, and our code has both C and C++ modules. Is there a way if an existing variable is set somewhere, would also cause to update debug global variables in structure as well.
I was thinking of setter functions , but this requires modification in every module.Instead is there a way to replicate functionality like valuechangeevent in JSF with C or C++.

Comment: If your code accesses global variables directly, you have to rewrite it anyway.

Comment: If it is for debugging purposes, sounds like it's time to dig out how debuggers do watches. If you use open source toolchain, this should be relatively easy, start by learning how to do this with debugger (like gdb) interactively, then check out debugger sources and start hacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the debug module contains all the pointers to the variables you are monitoring.

```
struct debug {
  int * pointer_to_var_1;
};

struct debug __debug__;
__debug__.pointer_to_var_1 = &var_1;
```

Now suppose `var_1` is changed somewhere, and you can directly see from `__debug__` by accessing:

```
*(__debug__.pointer_to_var_1)  //This is up to date
```

Otherwise, you will have to use a setter and change everything in the modules, or use an infinite loop or timer to monitor all the variables. There is no event registration for value change in C.

Comment: Thanks. will try this method.Also would Observable pattern in C++ be helpful for this kind of implementation.

Comment: @Rajesh There are many mechanisms in C++ and Java that will help.. but in C, you have to do it manually :(

Comment: Will see what I can get in C++ ,if C++ already have mechanism to do this I'll implement that and create a wrapper around it for c.

Comment: @Rajesh You can overload the `=` operator and it becomes a setter :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with some pre-processor trickery:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define myvar global_debug_thingy->myvar
#else
int myvar;
#endif
```

I don't think that you can do accessor functions, or notifiers this way as it would need different code for reading and writing, and preprocessor can't do this.

Comment: A new code to handle events/notifiers is also good for me.I'm not only dependent on debugger.Can you please brief more about it .